# listview item is not selected programmatically in C#

Tags: c#, listview, select, selection

I have seen all the Questions about this issue, but solutions seem to not apply in my case.

i am trying to select an item in a listview and i have the following:

```
ListView Matlab_Hst_Props;
...
//Matlab_Hst_Props.HideSelection == false;
//Matlab_Hst_Props.Items.Count == 4;

Matlab_Hst_Props.Invoke(new Action(() => Matlab_Hst_Props.Focus()));
Matlab_Hst_Props.Invoke(new Action(() => Matlab_Hst_Props.Select()));
Matlab_Hst_Props.Invoke(new Action(() => Matlab_Hst_Props.Items[0].Selected = true));

//Matlab_Hst_Props.Items[0].Selected == true

Matlab_Hst_Props.Invoke(new Action(() => Matlab_Hst_Props.Items[0].Focused = true));

//Matlab_Hst_Props.Items[0].Focused == false;!!!
//Matlab_Hst_Props.SelectedItems.Count == 0; !!!
```

Yes, i do this from a thread, but even if i dont use the thread and remove the `invoke`, i still have the same behaviour.

please help.
What could i be missing?

---

I would like to add here an update.
In fact my GUI is made up of tabs.
This ListView is in the third Tab. I get the error if i DON'T click on the third Tab and the ListView is Not drawn. 
iF i select the tab, and the ListView is Drawn before This piece of code is run, then the selection is done correctly.
What could it change drawing or not the Listview?
and how can i somehow force such an operation?

Answer (score 0):

I am posting here the workaround i use. I know this is just a silly workaround, but i still did not found out the true reason behind this behaviour.

In initialization process of the GUI, i change the tab programmatically to the Tab where the 
Listview resides:

```
Top_Tabs.Invoke(new Action(() => Top_Tabs.SelectedIndex = 2));
```

and then as initialization ends, i put it back on the first Tab

```
Top_Tabs.Invoke(new Action(() => Top_Tabs.SelectedIndex = 0));
```